# Starting WinAPI and Qt?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm starting to learn to program in the windows environment. Someone recommended me "Programming Windows 5th e" to start with. My questions is it mandatory to learn the windows GUI since Qt provide portability ?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It's quite mandatory if you want your application to look like a native Windows application. A lot of people like the Qt hackjob, though.

Comment: Do you want portability? If so then Win32 GUI isn't for you.

Answer (score 2):

One of the key features of QT as a development platform is its ability to produce cross-platform applications.

If you use the Windows API in a QT application then you're defeating that key feature, and therefore defeating the point of using QT. If you're going to do that, you may as well write your code with a Windows-specific framework like .NET and develop proper Windows software.

Comment: I agree with most of this, but I'm not sure why you'd write your code in .NET if you want to use the Windows API, either. The nice thing about the .NET Framework is that WinForms is an almost entirely complete wrapper around the Win32 API designed to shelter programmers from being exposed to its ugliness.

Comment: @Code - thanks for the comment. I wasn't trying to imply you should use the Win API in .NET; I've edited the question to try to clarify what I meant. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have programmed for Windows applications since year 2000. Windows API, MFC and ATL works fine for me. I can achieve anything that can be achieved using QT, WX or other GUI toolkits. Why do I need to put QT DLL/Library burden on my application.

And for nice-GUI/skinned look, I won't have any applications like that. In that case, anyone can use WPF. MFC/ATL is one of the thinnest layers over Windows API - QT is heavy. The signals and slots make program slow - I don't need dynamic-message handling.

Comment: MFC is thin?  lol!  Try maybe wxWidgets if you want a thin lightweight wrapper.

Comment: I have used wxWidgets, I already mentioned. It is quite easy to use, actually easier than MFC. But not as thin as MFC for Windows GUI development. CWnd::SendMessage is ::SendMessage(m_hWnd...) for example, at the thinnest level. Yes, for sockets, threads it is somewhat thick, but not as QT or WX. I will never use MFC for COM, where ATL is perfect and MFC is too bloated.

Comment: You seemed to be focused on event handling (Qt signals and slots).  MFC message maps are not a thin wrapper around the Win32 API, they're actually very complex and heavy.

Comment: I have debugged WX code on Windows, and it functions around PreTranslateMessage, DispatchMessage etc. to  eventually get the desired function to call. And I found the internal code of WX more complex than of MFC. As with QT, forget comparing, it doesn't bind most of the things at compile time - QT's signals/slots may cause runtime exceptions.
Think from a simple perspective - MFC is Windows only, it doesn't need to handle compatibility issues, how QT/WX can be faster? MFC/Windows is of MS, not third party - they know their own stuff! On VC10, revamped MFC wizard back for a reason!

Comment: Don't conflate Qt with WxWidgets. You're totally right about Qt being an enormously heavy wrapper, but WxWidgets has a very similar design to MFC and about the same performance costs and dependencies. It's basically just a cross-platform version of MFC, quite useful for someone who wants to write an app with an eye towards running on other platforms. That said, I don't really understand WxWidgets and have never felt quite comfortable with it, despite the fact that I actually *like* working in MFC. So individual mileage may vary.

Comment: Truly said, WX is nice wrapper around WinAPI. The Windows specific installation of headers, source-code and library makes is very similar to MFC (for one, handling compatibility at compile-time). I already mentioned WX is quite easy too. But when you have VS, why do you want to have another toolkit? As with cross-platform thing - not all OSs support all GUI features, they would fail.

Comment: Yes, WX uses `DispatchMessage` to call the right window procedure.  That's the Win32 way of doing things.  MFC also uses `TranslateAccelerators`, `DispatchMessage`, etc., but then it also uses complex message map garbage.  If you don't need dynamic message handling, then your choice should be WX, not MFC.  And don't get me started on MFC exception handling or serialization.  Seriously, it's hard to find more badly designed code.  You should try actually reading some of the MFC source before concluding it's similar to WX and a thin wrapper around the Win32 API.